# TFS Destroy /startcleanup - how do I start the clean up manually?

Tags: cleanup, team-foundation-server

I ran TFS Destroy on a file that was too long.

But I forgot to add the /startcleanup command.  It is now several days later and the file is still referenced in the TFS Database (or so says my migration tool).

The docs say that the cleanup defaults to run daily.  However, it seems to have not run.  I can't delete it again with the startcleanup command.

So how can I force TFS to clean that up now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by running the "TfsVersionControl Administration Job" via SSIS.

I found this info here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/3a81e86c-8434-4b3d-90dc-ced1e38f29bb/